# Give gas vs throttle

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> He gave too much gas and fell.
>
> He gave too much throttle and fell.

What sounds better out of the two? A person accelerated his motorbike too much and fell. Is there a better way to put it, more common and natural one?

Comment: As you know, requests for proofreading or phrasing improvements are not on-topic. For what it's worth, however, neither of your examples is idiomatic to me (AmE speaker); it sounds like he was donating gas to a charity. I would say something like *He gave it too much gas and fell off* or *He gave it too much throttle and fell off* but only informally; in more formal writing I would say *he accelerated too quickly.*

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to say about your example.

In the North American world, **gas** is frequently used to mean gasoline, a liquid fuel.

In the European world, **gas** means just that. So while Americans often put their foot on the gas, Europeans generally stamp on the accelerator or, at least, push it down hard.

**To give throttle** is internationally understood as slang for **to accelerate sharply**. So, yes, you could say that.

I have more often come across **to open the throttle**, which means the same thing - or in a motorcycle context, **twist the throttle (grip) open.**

From the context one assumes that you have already referred to the individual being on a motorbike. While **he fell** is adequate, **fell/came off** are more explicit.

Comment: I once talked to a railway engine driver who talked of taking a Class 47 hauled express out of York, and, to achieve a fast departure, he 'gave it the beans'.

Comment: Also, we can call a heavy throttle application 'giving it the gun', or '(very British) giving it some welly' - a wellington is a type of boot.